# shell script using echo and sed not working

Tags: shell

enter code hereI'm trying to filter logs for a particular time range from the available data.

For example :- An event happened around 11:00 AM due to which i lost connectivity on my edge router. So, now i am trying to go through a log file for the time period 10:50 - 11:05 to see what happened during this time frame.

I tried creating using this script and it's not working

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Filename"
read filename
echo "type start-time and hit [Enter]: "
read word1
echo "type end-time and hit [Enter]: "
read word2
sed -n '/$word1/,/$word2/p' $filename
```

If i issue the sed command without integrating into the script i can get the desired output. However, i am trying to execute it using a script where i input the values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the sed command like this:

```
sed -n "/$word1/,/$word2/p" "$filename"
```

The issue was that the shell does not expand variables inside single-quotes.  If you want to expand variables, such as `word1` and `word2`, then use double-quotes.

If you don't use either single or double quotes, then the results are subject to *word splitting* which is likely not something that you want.

Comment: example :- if the input for start time is 11:35, it works

Comment: if the input is "2015 Jul  1 11:36:29" then it's messed up

Comment: error which i am seeing is :- sed: 1: "/2015": unterminated regular expression

Comment: @GauravSud remove double quote from around `$word1` and `$word2`

Comment: Yes, in other words, try: `sed -n "/$word1/,/$word2/p" $filename`.  Also, for this approach, it is critical that the log file have at least one entry at the start and end times.  So, don't eneter `2015 Jul 1 11:36:29` unless the log file really does have an entry at 29 seconds after 11:36am.

Comment: Thanks everyone ... Finally got it working with your help.

Comment: @John1024. That's totally acceptable my friend.. :-)